# Understand......from?

Tags: word-usage, usage

I don't this that this sounds natural, but I'm not quite sure..  (Maybe this sentence sounds fine to me because I'm directly translating it from my native language...... Though when I think about it in English, it doesn't quite make sense...)

> I need to understand this concept from Ms. Brown.

That is, I need Ms. Brown (teacher) to explain a concept to me. Or should it be:

> I need to go to Ms. Brown to understand this concept.
>
> I need to understand this concept.
>
> I need Ms. Brown to explain this to me.

Comment: The last one is the most natural (if you want to include the teacher's name).

Comment: So @KateBunting my first sentence (understand from) is unnatural, right?

Comment: It isn't a natural way to express what you are trying to say. We sometimes say, for example "I understand from Ms Brown that you will soon be leaving the school, Mr Smith", as a polite way of letting Mr S know that you have heard the news from another person.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first one sounds somewhat natural, but it's a poor sentence.

> I need to understand this concept from Ms. Brown.

is leaving out the method in which you will receive your understanding. 
It's a short way of saying something like:

> I need to understand this concept from the explanation that Ms. Brown will give.

But this sentence is quite wordy, and probably wouldn't be used in a conversation. If you said the first sentence, you would definitely be understood, but I think the alternatives you provided are *much* better ways of getting the idea across, with your last example being the best.